# Random Whitespace/overflow on right side of website only on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, .net-6.0

I am not sure what is causing this.. I have been looking at different smart phone screen sizes in chrome dev tools mobile view, and that random white space on the right side of my page is always there. I can't see any element that has margin showing, or padding on that side.

I thought maybe it was the bootstrap row class causing it, and I made sure to add the row inside of a container-fluid div as the docs say to do.

The weird thing is, when I hover over every element on inspecting, they all show this white space on the right; even if I hover over the html tag... So I'm thinking the issue is bigger than bootstrap at this point.

I have tried adding the following with no changes.:

```
html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow-x: none;
}
```

When I'm in the mobile dev tools looking at the screen, I can drag and move the cursor left and right and the whole screen shakes to fill that right blank spot... So it is not behaving like it is using border-box..

When actually viewing the live site on my phone, this shaking back and forth doesn't happen, but I still see a slight white vertical space on the right side behind the cursor.. Idk if I'm being too picky and this is just space for the cursor in the phone settings? Although I see the same blank spot on every phone size in google chrome dev tools mobile view.. I know I'm not crazy! Well not completely yet!

Also, not that it helps in this situation(I think), my site is built using .NET Core 6 MVC. I am using Bootstrap 5. I am ready to start removing my media-query css line by line to see what could be causing it.. Its not an obvious issue, but I notice it of course.

If anyone has any idea what it could be, please let me know where to start.

[image: mobile view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I can't believe it but I had overflow-x: none, instead of overflow-x: hidden; I also had it on the wrong media query in my CSS.

Just glad I'm not crazy! lol

Answer (score 1):

You have to take into account that an element's width is not just the width itself, but a sum of its width, padding, border, and margin, and sometimes border-box doesn't fix the problem.

If you're using animations on scroll like a slide from left to right or vice versa can also screw your pages sometimes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).